# Magento 2 error - Product with Sku: prodotto not found in the catalog. - and the product exists

Tags: magento2, product, sku, not-found

I have only one product in the catalog with sku "prodotto". The product is in the default category, it is also visible on frontend (I can see it and browse to it on frontend), it is in stock, it has positive quantity. It is set to be visible and set to display in Catalog, Search, and it is enabled. I can see it in the table catalog_product_entity. However, when I try to check for this product by its sku ("prodotto"), I am getting the message:

```
Product with Sku: prodotto not found in the catalog.
```

This is my code:

```
$connection = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER) -> getObjectManager() -> get("\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection") -> getConnection();

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";

try {
    $count = $connection -> fetchAll($sql, array('prodotto'));
} catch (PDOException $pdoe) {
    echo $pdoe;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Why is this hapenning?

Comment: Are you sure there are no white spaces in your product SKU

Comment: There are no whitespaces anywhere in the database, on admin and in the code, in the sku.

Comment: Why are you approaching with a direct SQL access? You should use "ProductRepositoryInterface".

Comment: This is a task that I have to do, given to me.

Comment: It looks like I had some errors prior to the missing product method, and these I resolved with using the same PHP version in CLI as Magento 2 is using in web server (in the browser).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had some errors prior to the missing product method, and these I resolved with using the same PHP version in CLI as Magento 2 is using in web server (in the browser).